# Blender использует только 2-3% от gpu во время финального рендеринга

Tags: blender

При финальном рендеринге блендер использует только 2-3% от gpu и ~70% от процессора. В настройках проекта указана видеокарта для рендера. Как изменить это или так и должно быть?
[[image: Настройки проекта]

[image: Настройки блендера]

[image: Диспетчер задач]

Comment: Этот вопрос лучше разместить в сообществе, посвящённому Блендеру

Comment: настроено все верно, возможно, виндоус не видит загрузку CUDA

Comment: @Crantisz не могли бы вы объяснить по-подробнее?